# NDSolve diffusion equation NDSolve::ndnum

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a PDE.
My code is:

```
sol = NDSolve[{
        D[u[x, t], t] - D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + 4 D[u[x, t], x] -4 u[x, t] == 
             (3 - 2 t) e^(2 t) + (1 - 9 t) e^(-x),
        u[x, 0] == -1 , 
        (D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> 0) == -t, 
        (D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> 300) == 0},
       u[x, t], {x, 0, 300}, {t, 1.5, 100}
      ]
```

However it shows the following error:

> encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Mathematica is case-sensitive, so `e` is not the same as `E` (2.71...)

Comment: I changed it to E, but now I am getting new error: Could not solve for equations at boundary points from the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sol = NDSolve[{Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] - Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t] + 
4 Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t] -4 u[x, t] == (3 - 2 t) Exp[2 t] + (1 - 9 t) Exp[-x], 
u[x, 0] == -1,
Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == -t, 
Derivative[1, 0][u][300, t] == 0}, 
u[x, t], {x, 0, 300}, {t, 1.5, 100}]
```

This gives a result, which grows rapidly with t. You should check the pde.